# How to deploy default application settings

Tags: c#, .net, settings

Hi I need to provide each user with some default settings - list of string
Then each user can add new and sav?

I am using user-scope settings.

What are my options?

UPDATE:

I cant even find default settings in file in debug folder. So the question is what do I need tp deploy to user machine

Comment: I am using `XmlSerializer` and dedicated setting class (usually to edit settings in `PropertyGrid`). Because of XML, creating basic xml-file *without* any setting inside (or erasing them after deserialization) will cause deserializer to create object with default values of properties. Then simply include this config-file into installer. No idea what is *user-scope" restriction means, if it's all users/current user choice, then this is handled by installer.

Answer (score 0):

I would add class as AppSetting and make it serialize able.
Then I will add a ApplicationSettingManager it will look at a default path in such a folder like Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData if the setting file was there it will use it to deserialize   AppSetting if not it will save the default setting there (you can put default setting in AppSetting class or you can use app.config file beside .exe to have your default setting). whenever a user changed the setting ApplicationSettingManager  will over write the setting file.

```
   string ApplicationDataFolder
        {
            get
            {
                return Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData),
                        Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name);
            }
        }
        string UserSettingFilePath
        {
            get
            {
                return Path.Combine(ApplicationDataFolder, "Setting.xml");
            }
        }
 [Serializable]
    public class AppSetting
    {
        public AppSetting()
        {
           //default instantiation 
        }

        public int? CurrentUserId
        {
            get;
            set;
        }


    }
    enter code he
```

Look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder.aspx for different paths you can use

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`Settings` object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a65txexh.aspx) that is part of the Microsoft.VisualBasic library.

In C# you can access these through:

```
Properties.Settings.Default.FirstUserSetting = "abc";
```

And then save them out to disk with:

```
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

This will store them in an app specific directory under `Users\[UserName]\AppData\Local`

Alternatively, you can manage the serialization yourself and write them out to either `Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData` or `Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData`